# He was nervous to start. / He was nervous about starting

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Hope someone can help me.

(Talking about school)

*He was nervous **to start**, but I think it's going OK.*

Is "to start" correct/natural if he was nervous to start school, you know, before he started? Or what about "about starting", would that be better?

Thank you.

Comment: I would find **nervous about starting** much more idiomatic.

Comment: @KateBunting 100% agree, if the meaning is that *starting school* is the thing he's nervous *about*. If instead the same sentence were intended to mean he was nervous *at first*, but now he's doing fine, then OP might say, "He was nervous *to start with*, but I think it's going OK." *to start with* seems to be a fairly common expression: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nervous+to+start+with&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3